# Fundamental question of amortized analysis

Tags: big-o, amortized-analysis

A data structure supports an operation foo such that a sequence of n operations foo takes **Θ(n log n)** time to perform in the worst case.

> a) What is the amortized time of an foo operation?
>
> b) How large can the actual time of a single foo operation be?

a) First I assume foo is O(log n) worst case.
So the amortized cost comes from how often the foo tales its worst case. Since we know nothing further the amortized is between O(1) and log n

b) O(log n)

Is this correct? What is the proper way to argue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) if `n` operations take `Θ(n log n)`, then by definition the amortized time for a `foo` operation is `Θ(log n)` The amortized time is averaged over all the operations, so you don't count the worst case against just the operation that caused it, but amortized against all the others, too.

b) `foo` could occasionally cost `O(n)`, as long as it's not more than `O(log n)` times. `foo` could even occasionally cost `O(n log n)`, as long as that doesn't happen more than a constant (i.e., `O(1)`) number of times.

When you do amortized analysis, you don't multiple the worst case by the number of operations, but rather by the number of times that worst case actually happens.

For example, take the strategy of pushing elements into a vector one at a time, but growing the memory by doubling the allocated size each time the new element does not fit in the current allocation. Each doubling instance costs `O(n)` because you have to copy/move all the current elements. But the amortized time is actually linear, because you copy 1 element once, 2 elements once, 4 elements once, etc: overall you've done `log(n)` doublings but the sum of the cost of each of these is just `1+2+4+8+...+n = 2*n-1 = O(n)`. So the amortized time of this `push` implementation is `O(1)`, even though the worst case is `O(n)`.